# Sidebar at bottom however I have completely replaced theme folder back to original code

Tags: css, sidebar

Wordpress sidebar stuck at bottom despite replacing the entire theme file(works with other themes), Help please

I have been over the web and most people do not have the problem I have it seems. I have a similar problem of the sidebar being on the bottom. However many sites state that this is a coding error with a div tag, etc(I've quite a few)however I have replaced the theme folder and problem persist. (www.youauthorus.com, site with problem)

Additionally it seems as if the problem goes away when I switch themes. So I figured it is a problem outside the theme's code. It persist even when I use the unmodified original theme code.

how did the problem start, I was adding a text editor widget to the primary box. With a link to register and an image to register. I made the image a thumbnail and inserted it into post, but I think It had weird links in description tag(funky). This seemed to create a sidebar problem. I went and removed the widget and problem persist. Then I removed all widgets, view source code, changed files that had problem 8213(something like that). All the standard stuff and I even replaced the folder. I have uninstalled plugins, I have not slept so sorry if I am not concise.

I am on here because I have even done changes to the original files from Wp includes and admins. It seems wordpress is storing this information for memory of the theme(outside of theme). Where does this happen at, or doees any have a way to fix the problem or have fixed the problem I have. THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to note here:

1) You should never modify WordPress core files such as those found in "wp-includes" and "wp-admin" as it will only cause you trouble later down the road.

2) The sidebar issue you are reporting doesn't appear to be happening in Chrome on the link you provided. Try clearing the cache on your browser or doing a "hard refresh" on it to see if the issue is still happening.

3) If you've added custom markup code in your "text" widget, try removing that code temporarily and refreshing the page. If the problem goes away, review the code for any markup errors before putting it back in.

Comment: I actually fixed it by messing with core files(normally that is how I fix all wordpress problems as I find that easier but I will try to stop doing that(Search better ways). I have actually fixed the problem, it was messing up the mobile functions and the sidebar. It was actually in the post, because I looked through all the theme and core files. It like spontenaously generated once I broke it with widget(it and other deleted).
-
Your speedy response and warnings are greatly heeded D.S. Webster

Comment: Glad you were able to resolve the issue RJ. Just keep in mind that you run the risk of losing core edits any time you run a WordPress update. WordPress is a highly active community and the core team frequently releases security updates and major feature releases that make the platform even better over time. I'd hate to see you missing out on some fantastic new features because of core revisions in your projects. Best of luck!